# Display on another SharePoint-Site Content from a DIV located on any SharePoint Wiki Page [SharePoint 2013]

Tags: 2013, jquery, wiki, wiki-pages

On any Wiki-Page I have created a DIV:

```
<div id="content">This is the content which should be displayed on another site<br/></div>
```

Now, I would like to display this DIV on the Wiki Homepage. I have tried using following jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#content").load("https://mySharePoint/LinkToPageWhereDIVis.aspx #content");
</script>
```

However it doesn't display anything yet.

Is it maybe a wrong approach? If so, is there any workaround? Or is there any configuration setting in SharePoint which doesn't allow to display the DIV on another .aspx-Page?

I am using SharePoint 2013 on-premise.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#content").load("ajax/mySharePoint/LinkToPageWhereDIVis.aspx #content");
</script>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101770/load-content-of-a-div-on-another-page)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work yet adding "ajax" before the url. Did it work for you with this code? If so, then I think I have any configuration problem.

Comment: If you have added that content div in a html page, then try to refer to that html page link:

$("#content").load("ajax/SiteAssets/HTML/Test.html #content");

Comment: It is a Wiki-Page (based on Wiki-Page-Library App) with .aspx ending. The URL to that wiki page is: mySharePoint/minimal/05001/test/TestWiki%20fr%20Dokumentation/Skript%20Dokumentenexport%20von%20Polarion%20nach%20SharePoint.aspx

Comment: Have you added any CEWP in Wiki-Page referencing html file in CEWP?

Comment: I have used the edit source code functionality - so the solution without any webparts. But I can change it if you recommend me to do it this way.
On the page, where I want to display the DIV I have used a script editor webpart.

Comment: So on the new page where you have used a SEWP, make sure you have created a new div element with a different id and load the content div element from other page.
$("#result").load("ajax/https://mySharePoint/LinkToPageWhereDIVis.aspx #content");

Comment: First of all thank you for your further help.

I have generated a DIV above the jQuery code in the SEWP like this: <div id="result"></div>
I also used ur code. But it doesn't show up anything yet.

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no error message - so also not any hint where may be the mistake